# Streaming my UPS metrics for graphical viewing in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have an APC UPS, which comes with [the `apcaccess` utility](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apcaccess) to get various statistical values from [the `apcupsd` daemon](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apcupsd) service.

I am using the following script to stream my line voltage data to [thingspeak.com](https://thingspeak.com) website which allows us to see the results streaming in real time.

The script is set as a cron job, executing every minute.

```
#!/bin/bash

API_URL="https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&field%d=%s"
UPS_PROPS=(LINEV)

for index in ${!UPS_PROPS[@]}
do
    value=$(/sbin/apcaccess -up ${UPS_PROPS[$index]})
    curl $(printf $API_URL $(expr $index + 1) $value)
done
```

---

I have the `UPS_PROPS` as an array because I want to later extend the code to also stream some other data points.

The chart can be seen over [at this link](https://thingspeak.com/channels/463274/charts/1).

Comment: Next iteration is at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192255/creating-charts-for-my-ups-metrics-part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Good things

- Using `$()` over backticks (``` `` ```) for command substitution is a current best practice and does make code like this more readable.
- It is also good use variables for long unchanging items like your `API_URL`.
- Thanks for including the link to the graph.  This doesn't make your code any better, but it does lead to happier reviewers.  I'm such a fan of graphs I'd have thrown it inline.

## Suggestions

- Since you're using the `$()` form of command substitution, it is pretty easy to add some extra spaces inside of the parenthesis.  I think this makes it even more readable.  `$( /sbin/apcaccess -up ${UPS_PROPS[$index]} )`
- Using the variable as a `printf` format is a good way to do it, but that means the value of the variable isn't a valid URL.  If this were a bit longer than 10 lines it wouldn't hard to imagine a naive maintenance programmer coming along and doing `curl $API_URL` somewhere and wondering why it is giving him errors.  So I would prefer to name the variable `API_URL_FORMAT` or `API_URL_PROTO` to make it clear it isn't a usable URL yet.
- `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is considered more portable because it works with folks who can't install `bash` in the OS-proper place.
- Run your code through https://www.shellcheck.net/ for several hints about quoting your substitutions.
- It would be a bit clearer what's happening with the curl if you split it into two lines.  The first would set a variable like `ADDING_URL="$(printf $API_URL_FORMAT $(expr $index + 1) $value)"` then the second line would just be `curl $ADDING_URL`.  This leaves a pretty boring `curl` line I admit, but by using the variable it is easier to see what is happening with the `printf` before thinking about sending it out to the web.  And you may want more `curl` options later so the `curl` line could get more complicated.
- Please use consistent case for your variable names!  Some are upper case, which is pretty traditional for shell scripts, but other half are lower case.  Some people like upper case because it makes the variables stand out more.  I don't think that makes much difference with modern syntax highlighting editors.  But it should definitely be consistent, either way, in such a short script.  One convention is to use upper case for `export`ed/in the `env` variables and lower case for local/not in the `env` variables.  In the case all of your variables would be lower case since none of them are `export`ed into the `env`.
- Why are you looping over an array with one item in it?  Will it ever contain anything other than `LINEV`?  If not the code can be significantly simplified by getting rid of the `for` and just putting the values into the two inner lines.
- If the `for` loop has some value I would try to use it like a shell `for` loop and loop over the values instead of the indexes.  I see that you use the `index` inside of the `curl`, but I'm not sure what that is doing for you.

Comment: Thanks for those points. The array declaration of `UPS_PROPS` is intentional, and is mentioned in the question itself. I did run the script through shellcheck (emacs is configured for flycheck-mode); and I have updated the script in next few iterations a lot. I'll post a follow up soon.

Comment: I am using the `index` value as thingspeak API requires the fields to be indexed from 1, and like `field1=val1` and `field2=val2` etc.

Comment: As for inconsistent capitalisations, coming from python/lua primarily, I use `CAP_CASE` for globals and constants, and `snake_case` for local or changing variables. If there is a PEP or similar casing guidelines, I'd be happy to follow that practice.