# Creating charts for my UPS metrics - Part 2

Tags: bash, shell, stream

Following up from my previous question

> [Streaming my UPS metrics for graphical viewing in bash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/192167/12240)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[ -v METRICS_CHECK ] && set -x

API_URL="https://api.thingspeak.com/update"
UPS_PROPS=("LINEV" "LOADPCT" "TIMELEFT")
API_PARAMS=("api_key==XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

for index in "${!UPS_PROPS[@]}"
do
    value=$(/sbin/apcaccess -up "${UPS_PROPS[$index]}")
    field=$((index + 1))
    if [ "$field" -eq 2 ]
        then
        # bc required for floating point arithmetic
        value=$(echo "$value * 6" | bc)  # 600 Watt * load percent
    fi
    PARAM=$(printf "field%d==%s" "$field" "$value")
    API_PARAMS+=("${PARAM}")
done

/usr/local/bin/http "$API_URL" ${API_PARAMS[@]}
```

### Updates:

- Collects data for different metrics supported by `apcaccess`
- Use a variable check for enabling debug mode
- Split parameters sent to API URL into a different array
- Move away from `curl` to use `httpie`
- Custom computation for certain attributes

---

The shellcheck passes everything except the unquoted `${API_PARAMS[@]}` in the last line. I am not sure that `httpie` would work if I quote that and pass it as a single argument.

---

Charts for viewing pleasure (last 600 minutes data from the time post was created):

1. Input line voltage

   [image: LINEV]
2. Load (in wattage) on the UPS

   [image: LOADPCT]
3. Battery time left for the UPS

   [image: TIMELEFT]

Click the images to get live charts.

Comment: Can you edit the titles on those charts, so they are not all "voltage"?  (I know that's not part of the code, so this question isn't a review).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting - you need double-quotes on the last line: it should be `"${API_PARAMS[@]}"` (remember that the `[@]` makes the shell expand it into multiple words, so it won't be seen by your `http` program as just one).

Instead of `if [ "$field" -eq 2 ]`, it's clearer to compare the field name.  That will help if you change the properties list in future.  It may help to create a variable:

```
propname="${UPS_PROPS[$index]}"
value=$(/sbin/apcaccess -up "$propname")
if [ "$propname" = LOADPCT ]
```

We can supply standard input from a string without needing an `echo` process, by using `<<<` redirection:

```
    # bc required for floating point arithmetic
    value=$(<<<"$value * 6" bc)  # 600 Watt * load percent
```

We can make the array 1-based, and avoid the need to have `$field` different from `$index`:

```
UPS_PROPS=([1]="LINEV" "LOADPCT" "TIMELEFT")
```